# What exactly is a Link(Symbolic or otherwise)

Tags: java, file, io, hyperlink, nio

I was working on a java project with NIO.2 and I encountered the Files.createLink method. Upon doing some research on The Java Tutorials I found that these seem similar to windows shortcuts, but I'm not exactly sure if that's what they are. If they aren't how could I create a platform independent way to create a shortcut?

Comment: [Links, Symbolic or Otherwise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating a Symbolic Link**

> **If your file system supports it**, you can create a symbolic link by
>   using the createSymbolicLink(Path, Path, FileAttribute) method. The
>   second Path argument represents the target file or directory and might
>   or might not exist. The following code snippet creates a symbolic link
>   with default permissions:

**SOURCE:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html